# Can't Insert into MySQL Table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Having trouble inserting new records into a table. Anybody care to help?

```
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
<?php 

if(!empty($_POST['forename']) && !empty($_POST['surname']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['emailconfirm']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    if($_POST['email'] == $_POST['emailconfirm']) {
        $forename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['forename']);
        $surname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
        register();
    }
    else { $errormessage = "Emails do not match"; }
}
else { $errormessage = "Not all fields filled"; }

function register() {
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE EmailAddress = '".$email."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 1) {
        $errormessage = "Account already exists with the email address provided";
    }
    else {
        $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users (EmailAddress, Password, Forename, Surname) VALUES('".$email."', '".$password."', '".$forename."', '".$surname."')");
        $errormessage = "Account Added";
    }
}
?>
```

I think the problem lies within the MySQL Query Statement?

Comment: Are you receiving an error message?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Aaron W.: No error message, it inserts blanks into the Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in your `register` function are out of scope.  Need to globalize them.

```
function register() {
    global $email, $password, $forename, $surname, $errormessage;

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE EmailAddress = '".$email."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 1) {
        $errormessage = "Account already exists with the email address provided";
    }
    else {
        $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users (EmailAddress, Password, Forename, Surname) VALUES('".$email."', '".$password."', '".$forename."', '".$surname."')");
        $errormessage = "Account Added";
    }
}
```

Comment: *Yikes!*  Don't reference them as globals.  Pass them in.  There is *no reason* for them to be considered globals here.

Answer (score 0):

No params pass to the function `register()`?? In this file, you want to use `register()` to add record to the sql. But how could the `register()` know what value should be use for `$mail` variable? 
You can use `global` in `register()` in this way:

```
global  $email, $password, $forename, $surname, $errormessage;
```

Or you can rewrite the `register()` as

```
function register($email, $password, $forename, $surname, $errormessage){....}
```

And pass the params to `register($email, $password, $forename, $surname, $errormessage)`